# Can Git "attach" local files to branches?

Tags: git

I'd like to be able to make local (never tracked, never committed) files "stick" to certain git branches.

For example, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
$ git checkout version1.0
$ make
$ ./myProject # 1.0 binary
$ git stick-to-current-branch myProject
$
$ git checkout version2.0
$ make
$ ./myProject # 2.0 binary
$ git stick-to-current-branch myProject
$ 
$ git checkout version1.0
$ ./myProject # 1.0 binary from above
```

I made up the "stick-to-current-branch" command, but is there something that does this for real?  I never want to commit these files; they're branch-specific but shouldn't be tracked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no option to "stick" a file that is not tracked by git in the checked out working directory of different branches. You can however "generate" the file during checkout ( like using a `post-checkout` hook  - run your `make` in the post-checkout hook so that the `myProject` binary is generated for the branch / version)

Answer (score 1):

(note: not for binaries)
If the content a `myProject` file is easily identifiable, you could use a [filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) in order to generate the right content for that file based on the current branch.

[image]

On each checkout, you would use the smudge script to generate the private file (as in "not versioned") '`myProject`', based on a template file '`myProject.tpl`' with all the right values for all the different branches.

Comment: I think running a `post-checkout` hook would be a better option, especially since this is a binary and I don't think this would work with binary files?

Comment: @manojlds: which is why my answer starts with "note: not for binaries" ;)